# How to add symbol on line center, and make the arrow aligns to line end point in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I have created the map with Mapbox, but I had a few problems. When I try to Place the icon in the center of the line and add the arrow to the line endpoint, it always fails.

I added Markers on Jorge Chavez International Airport(LIM) & Alejandro Velasco Astete International Airport (CUZ)

```js
const marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: '#5C7F74',scale:'0.8'})
.setLngLat([-77.11174632225463, -12.02384281134897])
.addTo(map);

const marker3 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: '#8BAAA1',scale:'0.5'})
.setLngLat([-70.15810500000016,-15.469970999998012])
.addTo(map);
```

then add a line to map, So far it's okay but I don't know how to build new layers, add arrows aligns to the line endpoint, or add a symbol on line center

```js
map.on('load', () => {
  map.addSource('route', {
      'type': 'geojson',
      'data': {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'properties': {},
          'geometry': {
              'type': 'LineString',
              'coordinates': [
                [-70.15810500000016,-15.469970999998012],[-77.10670100000081,-12.030560999998116]
              ]
          }
      }
  });
  map.addLayer({
      'id': 'route',
      'type': 'line',
      'source': 'route',
      'layout': {
          'line-join': 'round',
          'line-cap': 'round',
          'line-miter-limit': 2
      },
      'paint': {
          'line-color': '#888',
          'line-width': 3,
          'line-dasharray':[2,2]
      }
  });
});
```